# can not install spacy on ARM

Tags: arm, spacy

How do I install spacy on ARM processor? I get an error

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /root/miniforge3/bin/python3.7 /root/miniforge3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix /tmp/pip-build-env-ahxo0t0p/overlay --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- setuptools wheel 'cython>=0.25' 'cymem>=2.0.2,<2.1.0' 'preshed>=3.0.2,<3.1.0' 'murmurhash>=0.28.0,<1.1.0' thinc==7.4.1
```

Full error log:

https://gist.github.com/shantanuo/1fb62b83a54713e517307c9cad9624f5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to specify some additional settings to compile the dependency `blis` for the right architecture. The most basic option to try is:

```
BLIS_ARCH="generic" pip install spacy --no-binary blis
```

For more details and architecture-specific options, see: https://github.com/explosion/cython-blis#building-blis-for-alternative-architectures

Comment: Thanks. But it takes a lot of time. Is there any way to make it faster?

Comment: If you're compiling directly, no not really. You might look into cross-compiling python packages. I don't have any experience with this, though.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be attempting to compile against x86_64. At least there are plenty of references in the output you linked to. For example `gcc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-mavx2’` (AVX2 being an x86 extension). There are also include paths to x86_64. I question whether or not what you're trying to compile here really supports ARM at all.

Comment: There are many packages I have installed successfully using the command "pip install XXX". Does it mean spacy does not support ARM and hence can not be installed? Is there any tool that can help me install packages on ARM those works fine on other processor?